# Graphing of Timestamps from PostgreSQL and external program

Tags: excel, postgresql, graph, charts

I am looking for a way to graph the time a Toy Store stock boy was checking into his job. There would be a defined start and end time for the overall graph but looking to span the amount of time he/she spent on the job.

The actual database would simply have the times the stock boy checked into work and the time he/she clocked out. Example:

### timeshifts table

```
employerID |     start_time      |   end_time
---------------------------------------------
1          | 2014-12-10 09:00:00 | 2014-12-10 09:37:00
1          | 2014-12-10 09:53:00 | 2014-12-10 11:44:00
1          | 2014-12-10 12:00:00 | 2014-12-10 15:00:00
```

after extracting the data and importing into (??), my IDEAL graph output would look something like
[image]

I know PSGL can't do this on its own but not sure if I need to structure the data in any special format to calculate the X distance (something like an age(end_time,start_time) or the like).

Thank you for your help ahead of time!

Comment: You *probably* won't need to calculate the X distance. But exactly what you *do* need to do depends on which graphing software you choose. Graph with literals before you try to graph with data from the database.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' - I suppose finding the right software is the biggest issue. Right now I'm limited to Excel for this but can't think of a proper way to structure the data to define the length. Setting the height to on / off could be as easy as a 1 or 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, you can subtract timestamps.

```
select employer_id, start_time, end_time, end_time - start_time as elapsed_time
from timeshifts;
```

```
employer_id  start_time               end_time                 elapsed_time
--
1            2014-12-10 09:00:00-05   2014-12-10 09:37:00-05   00:37:00
1            2014-12-10 09:53:00-05   2014-12-10 11:44:00-05   01:51:00
1            2014-12-10 12:00:00-05   2014-12-10 15:00:00-05   03:00:00
```

Whether Excel can recognize the values in "elapsed_time" is a different thing. It might be easier to do the subtraction in Excel.

---

```
create temp table timeshifts (
  employer_id integer not null,
  start_time timestamp with time zone not null,
  end_time timestamp with time zone not null,
  check (start_time < end_time),
  primary key (employer_id, start_time)
);
insert into timeshifts values
(1, '2014-12-10 09:00:00', '2014-12-10 09:37:00'),
(1, '2014-12-10 09:53:00', '2014-12-10 11:44:00'),
(1, '2014-12-10 12:00:00', '2014-12-10 15:00:00');
```